# How can i copy non-binary files into my binaries directory with catkin and cmake?

Tags: ros, path, catkin, binary, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a benchmarking executable in my project which pulls data from bagfiles. Now I want to copy the folder with my bagfiles into the directory where my binaries end up, because I have hardcoded paths to them in my code. I already tried to copy the folder with my bagfiles by adding this line to my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
file(COPY src/benchmarking/bagfiles DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

Unfortunately the variable `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` only contains the absolute path to my source directory. Is there a variable that points to the binaries directory?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239587/how-can-i-copy-non-binary-files-into-my-binaries-directory-with-catkin-and-cmake?/) by [Robert Grönsfeld](https://answers.ros.org/users/27496/robert-gr%C3%B6nsfeld/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-15**:
Just a suggestion: if you place your bagfiles in a (skeleton) ROS pkg, you could use `rospack find $bag_pkg` to parameterise the location. Could potentially remove the need for hard-coded paths.

Alternatively, you could make the paths parameters, and provide the absolute paths at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution was to replace `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` with `${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}`

See also [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/182465/copying-files-in-devel-folder-cmakeliststxt/).

---

Originally posted by [Robert Grönsfeld](https://answers.ros.org/users/27496/robert-gr%C3%B6nsfeld/) with karma: 26 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0